# Updating data binding source of a content control in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to create a view that has a set of tabs (each, basically a `ContentControl`) that each have various settings. I then want to have a button that will update all of the data binding rather than updating instantly or having update buttons associated with the controls themselves

So, my control is MEF exported as a `ResourceDictionary` and is similar to the below

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
            <TabItem Header="Tests">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding ResultStorage}"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Update"/>
            <Button Content="Cancel"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

TestStorage would be like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:XmlResultStorage}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Result File Path:"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ResultPath, Source={x:Static properties:DataStorage.Default}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Result File Location:"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ResultFilename, Source={x:Static properties:DataStorage.Default}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I want to do is when the button to update is pressed to somehow call the update (`UpdateSource`?) on the `ContentControl` but I can't see how to do it.

In an ideal world I wouldn't have code-behind and do it all via MVVM or something, but if that's not possible code-behind is fine.

So I have two issues, how do I update data bindings manually via a `ResourceDictionary` and how do I then cause it to cascade through its child `ContentControls`?